# UPSERT with Entity Framework Core

Tags: entity-framework, ef-core-2.1

Need to update or insert in parallel scenario and racing conditions, using EF Core.
The only way that worked is to use try catch blocks. Nothing else worked.
I know that I can do an SP, but I want EF only...

This is the working code, nothing is broken, just a bit of mess...

```
                        var _be = new Models.BackgroundEntry()
                        {
                            Id = id,
                            Datetime = Int64.Parse(first_action.Value<String>("datetime")),
                            Part = part,
                            Domain = host,
                            Session = Guid.Parse(req.session_id),
                            Action = action.ToString(),
                            Location = req.location
                        };

                        context.BackgroundEntry.Add(_be);

                        try
                        {
                            await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            context.BackgroundEntry.Remove(_be);

                            _be = await context.BackgroundEntry.FindAsync(id, sessionGuid);

                            if (_be.Part.Length < part.Length)
                            {
                                _be.Part = part;
                                context.Update(_be);
                                await context.SaveChangesAsync();
                            }
                        }
```

Comment: You should never `catch` all exceptions and then try to handle.  `catch` the _specific_ exception that indicates that the row already exists.  And there's not really a better way to do this without using a native SQL query.  In SQL Server, eg, you could use a MERGE statement.

Comment: Call FindAsync first, if not found then "new" it up and Insert.

Comment: @mxmissile UPSERT is a performance oriented design pattern. There is no time to call FindAsync.